# spring and hibernate configuration using annotations

Tags: spring, hibernate, annotations

I was trying to configure sessionfactory and datasource configuration details from external properties file using annotations(no xml) with this  but i was getting the following exception.

```
 @Value("${hibernate.dialect}")
    private String hibernateDialect;
    @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}")
    private String hibernateShowSql;
    @Value("${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}")
    private String hibernateHbm2ddlAuto;

    @Value("${hibernate.driverClassName}")
    private String driverClassName;
    @Value("${hibernate.url}")
    private String url;
    @Value("${hibernate.username}")
    private String username;
    @Value("${hibernate.password}")
    private String password;

  @Bean

    public PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer()
    {
        PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer = new PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer();
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.properties"));
        propertyPlaceholderConfigurer.setIgnoreUnresolvablePlaceholders(true);
        return propertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
    }

    @Bean()
    public DataSource getDataSource() {
        System.out.println("**"+driverClassName+"&&"+url+"***"+username+"%%%"+password);
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName(driverClassName);
        dataSource.setUrl(url);
        dataSource.setUsername(username);
        dataSource.setPassword(password);

        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTransactionManager hibernateTransactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        hibernateTransactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return hibernateTransactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTemplate getHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory)
    {
        HibernateTemplate hibernateTemplate = new HibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
        return hibernateTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory()
    {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean localSessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
        localSessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(getDataSource());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setHibernateProperties(getHibernateProperties());
        localSessionFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(new String[]{"com.foodeebuddee"});
        return localSessionFactoryBean;
    }



    @Bean
    public Properties getHibernateProperties()
    {
        System.out.println("**"+hibernateDialect+"&&"+hibernateShowSql+"***"+hibernateHbm2ddlAuto);
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", hibernateDialect);
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", hibernateShowSql);
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", hibernateHbm2ddlAuto);
        return properties;
    }
```

Exception I got.

```
 Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [com/foodeebuddee/Application.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean com.foodeebuddee.Application.sessionFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:584)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1089)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:984)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getSingletonFactoryBeanForTypeCheck(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:840)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:771)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isTypeMatch(AbstractBeanFactory.java:539)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:384)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:353)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:463)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessorRegistrar.registerBeanDefinitions(EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.java:110)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:317)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:116)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321)
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:240)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:254)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:94)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:609)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:552)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:293)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:749)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:738)
        at com.foodeebuddee.Application.main(Application.java:191)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean com.foodeebuddee.Application.sessionFactory()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:573)
        ... 30 more
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property 'driverClassName' must not be empty
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:162)
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.setDriverClassName(DriverManagerDataSource.java:124)
        at com.foodeebuddee.Application.getDataSource(Application.java:111)
        at com.foodeebuddee.Application.sessionFactory(Application.java:140)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:166)
        ... 31 more
```

Any Suggestions Appreciative.

Answer (score 2):

Solution is in the error itself::::

> com.foodeebuddee.Application.sessionFactory()] threw exception; nested
>   exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Property
>   'driverClassName' must not be empty at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:188)

provide a suitable driverClassName like com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Answer (score 0):

driverClassName  is essential for creating session factory in Spring but its value is coming empty first you can do more logging and see that why the value of driverClassName is not coming .

Comment: yeah Deepak i search for that driverClassName  getting null value

Answer (score 0):

The `getPropertyPlaceholderConfigurer()` method should be static.

More details can be found [here](http://www.java-allandsundry.com/2013/07/spring-bean-and-propertyplaceholderconf.html)